# Issues connecting to (Mysql) database (running in docker-compose) from quarkus application

Tags: mysql, jdbc, docker-compose, quarkus

I have a quarkus application that is attempting to connect to a mysql database, both of which are running in docker-compose.  The application is up, and serving requests (here is a screenshot of the docker-compose logs showing both the quarkus app and mysql starting):
[![docker-compose start logs][1]][1]

To verify the quarkus app is working, I make a request to: *http://localhost:8080/health/liveliness*.  A screenshot is shown below:
[![liveliness check][2]][2]

The database is also up and available (to verify you can run *mysql -h 192.168.0.4 -P 3306 -u user -p*, and when prompted for the password, enter *password*).  You can see screenshots of me being able to login and run a few pseudo commands below:

However, when I make a request that involves running a query against the database, it always times out.  The full logs (including the stack trace) is shown below:

```
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 2020-09-07 21:59:51,526 INFO  [com.con.rea.int.DebugInterceptor] (executor-thread-1) Unique id: 6060ad67-723a-4899-afa4-0811ec9dc3b4 com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao.getAllAssessmentsthrew exception of type class com.connor.reading.exception.SystemException for parameters empty (no parameters)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 2020-09-07 21:59:51,526 INFO  [com.con.rea.int.DebugInterceptor] (executor-thread-1) Unique id: 6060ad67-723a-4899-afa4-0811ec9dc3b4 com.connor.reading.service.AssessmentService.getAssessmentsthrew exception of type class com.connor.reading.exception.SystemException for parameters NULL, NULL
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 2020-09-07 21:59:51,526 INFO  [com.con.rea.int.DebugInterceptor] (executor-thread-1) Unique id: 6060ad67-723a-4899-afa4-0811ec9dc3b4 com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl.getAssessmentsthrew exception of type class com.connor.reading.exception.SystemException for parameters NULL, NULL
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 2020-09-07 21:59:51,526 ERROR [com.con.rea.uti.ExceptionMapperImpl] (executor-thread-1) Handling error: com.connor.reading.exception.SystemException: There was an error when querying the database for all assessments.  The sql ran was select * from rc.assessments
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao.getAllAssessments(AssessmentDao.java:42)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao_Subclass.getAllAssessments$$superaccessor2(AssessmentDao_Subclass.zig:368)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(AssessmentDao_Subclass$$function$$2.zig:29)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor.handleAroundInvoke(DebugInterceptor.java:33)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor_Bean.intercept(DebugInterceptor_Bean.zig:385)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao_Subclass.getAllAssessments(AssessmentDao_Subclass.zig:326)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.service.AssessmentService.getAssessments(AssessmentService.java:32)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.service.AssessmentService_Subclass.getAssessments$$superaccessor1(AssessmentService_Subclass.zig:241)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.service.AssessmentService_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(AssessmentService_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:41)
reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor.handleAroundInvoke(DebugInterceptor.java:33)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor_Bean.intercept(DebugInterceptor_Bean.zig:385)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.service.AssessmentService_Subclass.getAssessments(AssessmentService_Subclass.zig:196)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl.getAssessments(AssessmentsApiImpl.java:28)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass.getAssessments$$superaccessor1(AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass.zig:211)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor.handleAroundInvoke(DebugInterceptor.java:33)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.interceptor.DebugInterceptor_Bean.intercept(DebugInterceptor_Bean.zig:385)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass.getAssessments(AssessmentsApiImpl_Subclass.zig:166)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.controller.AssessmentsApiImpl_ClientProxy.getAssessments(AssessmentsApiImpl_ClientProxy.zig:195)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:638)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:504)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:454)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:456)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:417)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:488)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:259)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:160)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:163)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:245)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:132)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:37)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:94)
reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | Caused by: com.connor.quarkus.jdbc.QuarkusDataAccessException: An error occurred
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.quarkus.jdbc.QuarkusJdbcTemplate.query(QuarkusJdbcTemplate.java:31)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.connor.reading.dao.AssessmentDao.getAllAssessments(AssessmentDao.java:39)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   ... 61 more
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:419)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:401)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   ... 2 more
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | 
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   ... 13 more
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_net_ConnectException_2_0002e_0003cinit_0003e_00028Ljava_lang_String_2_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    reading-comprehension-ws_1  |   ... 16 more
```

Repository link: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension (on branch ***9-list-all-assessments***)

The contents of the Docker compose file (used to run the database and application) can be found here: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml.  For convenience, please find the contents below:

```
#This file is NOT ever intended for use in production.  Docker-compose is a great tool for running
#database with our application for acceptance testing.
version: '3.3'

#Assign a static ip to the database so that it runs the same on gitlab ci server (as the localhost alias does not work with docker:dind as a service)
networks:
  network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'rc'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.4
  reading-comprehension-ws:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
volumes:
  my-db:
```

For those unfamiliar with quarkus, it works similar to spring, in that it autowires/injects a datasource based on values set in the application.properties.  You can find this file here: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/src/main/resources/application.properties, and I've also included the source below:

```
#Adding reflection config for generated models as well as properties file containing sql -> https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json, -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json

#database (mysql) stuff -> https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=root
quarkus.datasource.password=password
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4:3306/rc
#the below doesn't seem to execute on startup, which makes me think it can't connect at all
#quarkus.datasource.new-connection-sql=CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS RC
```

To run the application, use this file: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/run-it.sh

Any ideas on what to look at (application.yaml, build.gradle, etc)?
Thanks,
Connor
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hmry.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nHip.png

Answer (score -1):

Your service is unable to connect to your database, try adding the below to your service 'reading-comprehension-ws':

```
environment:
  quarkus.datasource.url: "jdbc:mysql://db:3306/{your-schema name}"
```

You need to replace {your-schema name} with your real schema name.

Since they are running in same docker-compose network, your service should be able to lookup your DB by service name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have also added the schema name as part of the url in the application.properties, and it still does not work.  Is there a need for quotes or environment variables?

Comment: Can you post your full docker-compose please and connection string used by your quarkus app.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help; I appreciate it!  I've updated my answer to show the jdbc connection string, as well as the rest of the application.properties.  It's also interesting to note that if i put the wrong host in the jdbc string, I get a completely different error (not able to connect at all) as opposed to the timeout I am currently getting.  Thanks again.

Comment: Try to execute batch command from your service container and try to do telnet to DB to check if it is accessible or not. To execute batch from your  container do : docker exec -it {container-id or container-name} /bin/bash.

Comment: I've once again verified I can connect to the container (both by executing a command using docker exec, and by connecting using the mysql and mysqladmin from my local machine, both of which work).  If I had to guess, I believe this is something agroal specific that I need to adjust.  Do you have any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: That's weird! Can we do this experiment, I know you need it, but just to verify our search area, try to remove docker network configuration from your docker-compose and adjust your connection string as I mentioned in my answer (by service name).